# Re-formatting a class correctly

Tags: python, class, graph

I have hurriedly written this 'class' which takes (for initialization) the textual representation of graph (as a string) and constructs a graph object.

The first line (header) describes the type of the graph and the number of vertices. It has two or three parts. The first part is either the character D indicating a directed graph, or the character U indicating an undirected graph.

If the graph is weighted, the second part of the header is the character W.

The last part of the header is a natural number n indicating the number of vertices in the graph. All the vertices in the graph are numbered from 0 to n-1.

If the graph string has more than one line, each remaining line (starting from the second line), describes an edge. The first two parts of an edge are two natural numbers between 0 and n-1, describing an edge between the two vertices identified with these numbers.

If the graph is directed, the two numbers must be interpreted as an ordered pair describing an edge from the first vertex to the second vertex. If the graph is undirected, the two numbers must be interpreted as an unordered pair describing an edge between the two vertices.

If the graph is weighted there will be a third part which will be an integer indicating the weight of the edge.

The graphs can be both directed or un-directed, and weighted or non-weighted
For example this graph:

```
graph_string = """\
D W 3
0 1 7
1 0 -2
0 2 0
"""
print(Graph(graph_string).adjacency_list)
```

is directed and weighted, and the '3' next to these symbolize the number of edges (in this case 3).
The adjacency_list of this example would output:

```
[[(1, 7), (2, 0)], [(0, -2)], []]
```

The 'class' I have written does achieve this, but not in the way a class is supposed to act. I am a bit confused about how to turn this into a proper class, all I know of now is that it should have only:

```
class Graph:
def __init__(self, graph_string):
    self.directed  =  # true if directed, false if un-directed
    self.weighted = # true if weighted, false otherwise
    self.adjacency_list = # a list of lists
```

as the init, with separate methods/functions to achieve the rest.
Thank you for taking the time to read this, and any feel free to ask questions as this was very difficult to word.
My Class:

```
class Graph:    
def __init__(self, graph_string):
    self.graph_string = []
    graph_string = graph_string.splitlines()
    for i in graph_string:
        i = (i.split())
        self.graph_string.append(i)
    directed_helper = self.graph_string[0]
    directed_score = directed_helper[0]
    weighted_helper = self.graph_string[0]
    weighted_score = weighted_helper[1]
    self.weighted = weighted_score
    self.directed = directed_score
    self.graph_string.pop(0)
    if self.directed == ("D"):
        self.directed = True
    elif self.directed == ("U"):
        self.directed = False
    if self.weighted == ("W"):
        self.weighted = True
    elif self.weighted != ("W"):
        self.weighted = False
    if self.weighted == False:
        edge_number = graph_string[0]
        edge_number = list(edge_number)
        edge_number = edge_number[2]
        edge_number = int(edge_number)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(edge_number)]  
    elif self.weighted == True:
        edge_number = graph_string[0]
        edge_number = list(edge_number)
        edge_number = edge_number[4]
        edge_number = int(edge_number)
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(edge_number)]             
    if self.weighted == False:
        if self.directed == True:
            for s in self.graph_string:
                first_element = s[0]
                first_element = int(first_element)
                second_element = s[1]
                second_element = int(second_element)
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((second_element, None))
        elif self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                first_element = t[0]
                first_element = int(first_element)
                second_element = t[1]
                second_element = int(second_element)
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((second_element, None))
                self.adjacency_list[second_element].append((first_element, None))
    elif self.weighted == True:
        if self.directed == True:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                first_element = t[0]
                first_element = int(first_element)
                second_element = t[1]
                second_element = int(second_element)
                third_element = t[2]
                third_element = int(third_element)
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((second_element, third_element))
        if self.directed == False:
            for t in self.graph_string:
                first_element = t[0]
                first_element = int(first_element)
                second_element = t[1]
                second_element = int(second_element)
                third_element = t[2]
                third_element = int(third_element)
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((second_element, third_element))
                self.adjacency_list[first_element].append((first_element, third_element))
    (self.adjacency_list)
```

This class does give the correct answer, however when adding new functions/methods the class fails to read them properly. We are also recommended to only have the variables self and graph_string in the **init** method.

Comment: I would give all `self.weighted` etc.. an initial value of False, `elif self.weighted` is the same as `elif self.weighted  == True`, just a more idiomatic way to check as is `if not self.weighted` but they can only be one so if it is not one it is the other, you also repeat code unnecessarily.

Comment: I made a few  changes to you code http://pastebin.com/dMdGxN27

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that is really hard to answer because, it is subjective.

But my first suggestion would be to try:

Splitting the code on smaller sub units IE:

- a method to parse the string to get the lines
- a method to process each row

If you are writing the same code multiple times, you will want to separate that on a method

Hope it helps